# How to Use Variable Expression for Default Value of Dashboard Prompt in OBIEE 11g

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

I need to create a Dashboard, where I can fill out one Dashboard prompt and set some request variables, and then have the default values in another dashboard prompt, or the prompt for an analysis be based on the variables set in the first prompt.

I have tried using the Variable Expression option to set the default values in the prompts, but it only uses the values of the session variables, not the temporary values in the request variables. Is there any way to do this?

Right now I have `@{biServer.variables['NQ_SESSION.TestVar1'] * biServer.variables[NQ_SESSION.TestVar3']}` as the default value for a variable prompt. I need it to be the values of TestVar1 and TestVar3, that were applied in a previous prompt as request variables,  multiplied, but all I get is the original values from the session variables.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need to use session or request variables? Is there a reason you can't use user variable?